# Unity: Distance between two game-objects in the scene view

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and as I am creating my interface, I am trying to find what's the distance between two game objects. I know how to do in a C#/javascript script, however I am strugling to find this information in the scene view. Any key I could press while moving an object to see the distance to its neighbours ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a script, you can use [Vector3.Distance](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Distance.html) between vector3 to get the distance between two points. Every gameObject has a position that is represented in a Vector3.

Below is a script example that shows you how it works. You just have to drag the script onto a gameObject in your scene and drag in the inspector another gameobject in your scene. The script should run even when your not in play mode because of the [ExecuteInEditMode].This way you will see the distanceBetweenObjects update in real time without actually having to hit play.

```
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class DistanceBetweenTwoObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject obj;

    public float distanceBetweenObjects;


    private void Update()
    {
        distanceBetweenObjects = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, obj.transform.position);
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, obj.transform.position, Color.green);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        GUI.color = Color.black;
        Handles.Label(transform.position - (transform.position - 
        obj.transform.position)/2, distanceBetweenObjects.ToString());
    }
}
```

The method OnDrawGizmos will draw text in between the 2 objects showing the distance value to help make it more user friendly.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any built-in functionality for this, but it's fairly trivial to add such a readout into the display using [ExecuteinEditMode], which causes scripts to run even when the game is not in play mode. This script, for example, should readout the distances on different axes and in total:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class EditorDistanceDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject target1;
    public GameObject target2;
    public float distanceX;
    public float distanceY;
    public float distanceZ;
    public float distanceTotal;

    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 delta = target2.transform.position - target1.transform.position;
        distanceX = delta.x;
        distanceY = delta.y;
        distanceZ = delta.z;
        distanceTotal = delta.magnitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: Its more performant than .Distance